# Building Emails inserting blocks dynamically

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dynamic-content

I am trying to define a very generic Dynamic Email Template inserting content blocks dynamically.

It is possible to insert blocks dynamically using AMPscript and the `ContentBlockByName/ID` functions?

Comment: This is a very broad and general question. I would hone this down and provide more use case and good faith attempts. As it stands currently, the answer to your question is just: yes. Which is not really helpful to anyone.

Comment: You are right. Thanks for your comment Gortoningtin. I was just trying to use this ContentBlockByName function  in a loop but having issues. I just realized that my AMPSCript code was not well written. Now  it is working. In case could be useful for someone, here you have my code:

Comment: '%%[for @i = 1 to 3 do]%% %%[IF @subject == "The Subject ASICS333" THEN]%% %%=ContentBlockByName(@header)=%% %%[ELSE]%% %%=ContentBlockByName(@footer)=%%%%[ENDIF]%% %%[next @i]%% '

Answer (score -2, accepted):

try like this if you use if conditions means

```
  %%[if @cond1=='somthing' then]%%
  %%=ContentBlockById(content block id here)=%%
  %%[endif]%%
```

Comment: There is an error in your ampscript `=` should be `==`  and this post does not offer any additional information which has not been mentioned in the comments above. The only thing you could add is that there are different methods to get a content block: `ByID, ByKey and ByName` and each of them has its right to exist with pros and cons.

Comment: i have used now  == instead of = for me its working

Comment: Can you please watch on the last comment from @Enrique Diaz that has been done directly under the question. It has been posted 9 hours ago and your answer does not offer additional information therefore it has no right to exist (my point of view).

Comment: @JohannesSchapdick--> they make me my answer is best  check above once